# How to install drivers in linux

Tags: linux, drivers, intel-graphics

My screen flickers a lot while changing apps . Most in vlc when changing volume . So I thought maybe the drivers are wrong so I checked and found that my linux is using i915 .

I dont know if it is the correct one . Please help me I am using Antix 19.2

My graphic card : Intel 3rd gen graphics

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Sorry but can you help me  how to find correct driver